# Write function as a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to create a context driven menu. This menu comes when the user clicks on any of the nodes in the tree. Each node has a class "treedropdownmenu". On node clicked, the context driven menu should open up. I am passing a method "_deleteClick" with the Delete menu option. But it is throwing me an error : "_deleteClick" menu not found.

I have following fine of code in my widget :

```
$(".treedropdownmenu").live("click", function (event) {
    var pos;
    if(($(window).height() - event.pageY) < 80) {
        pos = {
            left: event.pageX + 20,
            top: event.pageY - 60
        };
    } else {
        pos = {
            left: event.pageX + 20,
            top: event.pageY + 20
        };
    }
    if(ko.dataFor(this).nodeId() && ko.dataFor(this).nodeId() !== 0) {
        var item = ko.dataFor(this);
        var strHtml = "<a href='#' onclick='_deleteClick(item)'>Delete:</a> " + "<br/>" + "<b>Create Date:</b>" + "<br/>" + "<b>Exposed Party Name:</b>" + "<br/>" + "<b>Portfolio Type:</b>" + "<br/>" + "<b>Owner:</b>";
        $("#dataManagerMenuItem1234").show().offset(pos).html(strHtml);
    }
});
```

The delete menu I have is  :

```
function _deleteClick(item) {
    alert("delete clicked");
}
```

Can anyone let me know where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I don't think that will work.  Try this:

```
var strHtml = "<a href='#'>Delete:</a> " + "<br/>" + "<b>Create Date:</b>" + "<br/>" + "<b>Exposed Party Name:</b>" + "<br/>" + "<b>Portfolio Type:</b>" + "<br/>" + "<b>Owner:</b>";
 $("#dataManagerMenuItem1234").show().offset(pos).html(strHtml).find('a').click(function() { _deleteClick(item); });
```

Answer (score 1):

This is kindof a clumsy way of adding an event handler to the link, especially
since you're creating it programmatically anyways. Why not add the click
handler dynamically, like so?

```
var item = ko.dataFor(this);
var deleteLink = $('<a>', {
    href: '#',
    click: function() {
        _deleteClick(item);
    },
    text: 'Delete:'
});
$("#...").show().offset(pos).append(deleteLink);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not addthe event handler in a string, that is bad practice.

```
var strHtml = "<a href='#'>foo</a>;
var lnk = jQuery(strHtml);
lnk.on("click", function(){ _deleteClick(item); });
$("#dataManagerMenuItem1234").show().offset(pos).append(lnk);
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted all your code here, but I assume you have defined the function `_deleteClick` in a local scope, and your onclick handler cannot access it from the global scope. This is one of the reasons why you shouldn't use `onclick` attributes to attach events to DOM elements! Your onclick attribute, written out as a string, is not going to execute in the right context. Use jQuery to subscribe instead.

It looks like you're using KnockoutJS. An even better way to do this would be using a [Knockout template](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html) to write out your menu.